# How to draw horizontal ray lines on high/low of previous candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to draw horizontal lines on high/low of previous candle on a specific timeframe.
(I will call this "reference" timeframe)[1H example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55i6k.jpg)

1. How do I code this so that this updates at every new candle in real time?
2. And how do I make it so that no matter what timeframe I choose afterward, the horizontal lines from the "reference" timeframe stays there.
   [1m example with 1H lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrBiO.jpg)

I tried this code but this only applies to Daily timeframe as reference and I would like to be able to change the "reference" timeframe in the settings.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

d_h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
d_l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(d_h, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green)
plot(d_l, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red)
```